# Cannot send embed and components discord.js v13

Tags: button, discord.js, embed

I can't send a button with my embed on discord.js v13, the bot only send the embed and not the button. I got an error "Invalid from body" but i don't know what i have to do?

Here is my code :

```js
        const embedopen = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Bonjour ${button.user.tag}, bienvenue dans votre ticket. Un <@&799060000122994698> ou l'<@&799049340538191892> va s'occuper de vous.`)
            .setTimestamp()
        const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new Discord.MessageButton()
                    .setLabel("Fermer le ticket")
                    .setCustomId("close_ticket")
                    .setEmoji('❌')
                    .setStyle("red")
            )

        channel.send({embeds: [embedopen], components: [row]})
```

And here is the error :

```
 04:55:06 -> [ERR] -> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
components[0].components[0].style: This field is required
    at RequestHandler.execute (h:\Users\Zarcross\Desktop\SiteComplet\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (h:\Users\Zarcross\Desktop\SiteComplet\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (h:\Users\Zarcross\Desktop\SiteComplet\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/902752250697515048/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [Array],
      components: [Array],
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a red button, change `.setStyle("red")` to `.setStyle("DANGER")`

You got the error because "red" is not a valid button style.

There are currently five different button styles:

`PRIMARY` - a blurple button

`SECONDARY` - a grey button

`SUCCESS` - a green button

`DANGER` - a red button

`LINK` - a button that navigates to a URL.

Comment: It works for me now ! I forgot this changement int the v13